# Drive logic signals when power might be off

Tags: spi, interface

I'm designing a board that interfaces two systems with an SPI signal. Each system has a 5V power supply, and I have access to both supplies, but either supply may be turned off at any time. How should I drive and receive the SPI signals so that I don't drive current into powered-off logic?

Low power design is not necessary, and the SPI speed is only 31kHz, so answer one is to just put in series resistors. That's ugly :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a buffer such as a [NC7SZ126](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/NC/NC7SZ126.pdf)- they have high output and input impedance even when powered down.

You might still want to include resistors if the two units are not close to each other and in the same enclosure. Something around 1K will prevent problems if something transient happens.

Comment: Looks like a good solution for my stated question; much smaller than two of the 74LVC8T245 parts. Although the way the design is going, I may well use those parts too to translate between a 3.3V micro and the other 5V interface which has many pins.

Answer (score 3):

Use dual-supply translating buffers like the [74LVC8T245](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74LVC_LVCH8T245.pdf). They are designed for partial power down, so supply voltages A and B can be switched arbitrarily. For bidirectional SPI, you will need two of them (one for SCK, SS, and MOSI and another for MISO).